# Working out the bounding box of a coutnry

Tags: web-services, geolocation

I'm wondering if there is a service that to get a set of lat,long points that when connected into a polygon show the outline of a country

Ideally I would like to search by country, and get back an array of lat,long coordinates. Is there such a service?

Comment: Are you sure you want the bounding box, or just the boundary?

Comment: just the boundary really - I want to be able to draw it on top of a google map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IF you are happy to consider not using a webservice, this data is available at varying resolutions from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).  The data is in the [public domain](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/).

Answer (score 6):

have a closer look here;

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:The_Anome/country_bounding_boxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User%3aThe_Anome/country_bounding_boxes)

> User:The Anome/country bounding boxes A first hack, based on all
>   places in the NGA GNS dataset, not (yet) properly handling latitude
>   wrap-round at ±180°. Country names are mapped from FIPS country codes.
>   This works pretty well for all countries that do not cross the 180°
>   meridian. Russia is a notable exception. This dataset does not include
>   the United States.

```
country        longmin   latmin  longmax   latmax

 AA             -70.983   12.400  -69.850   12.617 
 Antigua_and_   -62.417   16.817  -61.650   17.750 
 United_Arab_    45.000   22.167   59.250   26.133 
 Afghanistan     60.433   29.150   75.033   38.484 
 Algeria         -8.700   18.027   70.554   37.203 
 Azerbaijan      44.783   38.417   50.858   41.911 
 Albania         19.000   39.583   21.050   42.659 
 Armenia         43.443   38.857   46.589   41.300 
 Andorra          1.417   42.433    1.783   42.650 
 Angola          10.000  -33.806   24.350   -3.033 
 Argentina      -73.533  -58.583  -53.367  -21.783 
 Australia      112.467  -55.050  168.000   -9.133 
 AT             122.983  -12.667  124.050  -12.000 
 Austria          1.200   46.373   19.000   49.017 
 AV             -63.667   18.150  -62.917   18.600 
 Bahrain         45.000   25.000   50.954   26.566 
 Barbados       -59.667   12.967  -59.383   13.333 
 Botswana        20.000  -28.517   29.350   24.583 
 BD             -64.908   32.233  -64.617   32.417 
 Belgium          2.367   49.500    6.400   51.683 
 Bahamas        -86.000   20.000  -70.000   29.547 
 Bangladesh      84.000   20.600   92.683   26.817 
 Belize         -89.950   15.000  -75.000   18.483 
 Bosnia_and_H    15.746   42.558   19.671   45.268 
 Bolivia        -69.650  -26.867  -57.550    9.678 
 Burma           91.833    6.000  102.000   28.350 
 Benin           -4.000    5.000   92.219   21.322 
 Belarus         22.550   50.717   32.850   56.133 
 Solomon_Isla  -130.000  -45.000  170.200    3.751    WRAPPED
 Brazil         -73.817  -33.733  -28.850   16.800 
 BS              39.700  -21.417   39.700  -21.417 
 Bhutan          80.000   26.217   92.717   30.000 
 Bulgaria        22.371   41.000   28.600   44.215 
 BV               3.278  -54.467    3.483  -54.386 
 Brunei         110.000   -2.000  120.000   15.000
```

Answer (score 3):

[Yahoo! GeoPlanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/), the service Stack Overflow are using [for their careers site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london) seems to do bounding boxes.

Here is a [blog post with detailed query examples](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/showing_world_with_yql/).

Answer (score 1):

This repo contains a set of square bounding boxes. Example below:

```
{
  "AF": ["Afghanistan", [60.5284298033, 29.318572496, 75.1580277851, 38.4862816432]],
  "AO": ["Angola", [11.6400960629, -17.9306364885, 24.0799052263, -4.43802336998]],
  "AL": ["Albania", [19.3044861183, 39.624997667, 21.0200403175, 42.6882473822]],
  "AE": ["United Arab Emirates", [51.5795186705, 22.4969475367, 56.3968473651, 26.055464179]],
  "AR": ["Argentina", [-73.4154357571, -55.25, -53.628348965, -21.8323104794]],
  "AM": ["Armenia", [43.5827458026, 38.7412014837, 46.5057198423, 41.2481285671]],
  "AQ": ["Antarctica", [-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, -63.2706604895]],
  "…"
}
```

**Full set of boxes:**

https://github.com/sandstrom/country-bounding-boxes