# Getting bounding-box of city

Tags: gis

I want to know how far a specific geographic coordinate is from a list of cities ('far' meaning the euclidean distance between the coordinate and the city, not taking roads into account). For this I need to find a bounding-box for each of the cities - all located in Israel.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187402/working-out-the-bounding-box-of-a-coutnry) discusses country bounding-boxes, but I need them at the city level.

Is there any way to get this information for a long list of cities, other than drawing rectangles by hand on a map and extracting the coordinates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the bounding box of those cities at [www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php](http://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php). Entering a city will display a box on a map and give the latitude and longitude of each side. Hopefully that will give you the information you need.

Comment: The web app from mapdevelopers is not working anymore.

Answer (score 6):

For a long list of cities, use the [Google Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). Once you get set up, you can use any language to access the REST API. For example you could use the popular standard [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for Python.

Or, you could use Google's own Google Maps [Java API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/), [Python API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python), or [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding). Any of these contain the Google Geocoding service.

See some simple examples of the Python and Java library here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library.

Here's the schema for the Geocoding results:

```
results[]: {
 types[]: string,
 formatted_address: string,
 address_components[]: {
   short_name: string,
   long_name: string,
   postcode_localities[]: string,
   types[]: string
 },
 partial_match: boolean,
 place_id: string,
 postcode_localities[]: string,
 geometry: {
   location: LatLng,
   location_type: GeocoderLocationType
   viewport: LatLngBounds,
   bounds: LatLngBounds
 }
}
```

The bounding box is located in the `geometry>viewport` variable and looks like this

```
"viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
              "lng" : -122.0829009197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
              "lng" : -122.0855988802915
           }
        }
```

Comment: The `geometry` object is only available for the address itself not the city it is contained in, how to get the vieewport of the parent city?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the bounding box of those cities at
http://boundingbox.klokantech.com/
Entering a city/country will display a box on a map and give the latitude and longitude of each side. But accuracy is higher then at http://www.mapdevelopers.com/geocode_bounding_box.php (thx to @Fred for his answer)

Comment: What do you mean by accuracy and how is it better than that?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need not bounding boxes, but city boundaries. Because with bounding boxes your analysis will be very rough, and to get a bounding box you anyway firstly need a boundary.

If you have now just list of cities, you need to get spatial data, the boundaries of all your cities. To find this data you can try [this links](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/are-there-any-free-administrative-boundaries-available-as-shapefiles). I would suggest to check Open Street Maps. Then you can use any GIS software (for example, open-source Quantum GIS) and calculate there the euclidean distances between your point and the city boundaries.

Hope this helps.