# Latitude/Longitude dataset for country borders

Tags: latitude-longitude

I'm writing a program to display the expected lifetime of our product as it relates to average weather conditions in various locations across the globe and I'd like my map to reflect the latest country borders.

Can anyone recommend somewhere to get a dataset of latitude/longitude points for the world's latest country borders?

Comment: It's not clear how country borders can help in determining weather conditions. There are a lot of countries with absolutely different climatic zones. It looks like you could better count average conditions from latitude and season.

Comment: I've got the weather data taken care of, the question was how to get the points for the country borders alone.

Comment: see my answer below, this is what you need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the world country borders for free from Natural Earth:

[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/)

Layer Admin 0 contains the country borders

Comment: I think his is for gis applications. Can you tell how the files can be read from c or objective c?

Answer (score 8):

I'm aware this question is three years old, but someone might find this useful:

If a somewhat rough outline is acceptable, you may want to have a look at these KML files: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1uL8KJV0bMb7A8-SkrIe0ko2DMtSypHX52DatEE4#rows:id=1

I only needed the Germany file, so I only tested that one, but I found it to be quite satisfying for my purpose. The border is described with about a hundred coordinates and major islands are included as well.

There is also a second set of KMLs which are even more generalised, but include more islands (again, at least for the Germany file): https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1zn8cjdD6qlAFI7ALMEnwn89g50weLi1D-bAGSZw#rows:id=1

Comment: the google links doesnt worrk now

Answer (score 5):

The most accurate dataset that I have found is from "Global Administrative Areas"

[https://gadm.org/data.html](http://www.gadm.org/country)

You can download files per country in your preferred format. I think it is the dataset used by Google Earth as well.

Comment: Only for non-commercial use.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google's Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to find the bounds of any country or city area, etc, as discussed in this answer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31305319/243392.